# Error when using string variables in the table command

Tags: stata

Why does Stata complain with a cryptic error when I use string variables in the `table` command?

Consider the following toy example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
decode foreign, g(foreign_str)
table foreign, contents(n foreign_str mean mpg)
```

This raises an `r(111) variable __000002 not found` error in Stata 13.1.

Tracing the error tells me that it is trying to run `format __000002 %9.0gc` and crashing when it does not find the variable. If I switch the order of the variables in the `clist`, that is i run `table foreign, contents(n mpg_rank mean mpg)`, I get the same error but with `__000003` instead of `__000002`.

So it appears that Stata crashes when it finds the string variable. If I replace the string variable with a numeric variable, the error doesn't occur.

I know it is not meaningful to compute summary statistics on string variables, but counting the number of observations of a string variable (in each group specified by the rowvar) makes perfect sense.

Comment: You can use `table foreign, contents(freq mean mpg)` to get around this.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Right, that does exactly what I want; I'm mainly curious as to why Stata throws *this* (in my opinion) cryptic error. It seems like the function should check for string variables first, and throw a type mismatch or string variable not supported error, instead of a variable not found error (since the variable obviously exists).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know the answer.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov see my answer about why this happens in Stata 13.

Answer (score 1):

Stata complains because variable `__000002` (or `__000003` if you change the order) is not created by the `collapse` command (which is used internally by `table`) due to the following error:

```
collapse (count) foreign_str
type mismatch
r(109);
```

What really happens is not visible to the user because `capture` is used in combination with `collapse` and the output from `trace` confirms that:

```
- capture collapse `clist' `wgt', by(`varlist' `by') fast `cw'
= capture collapse  (count) __000002=foreign_str (mean) __000003=mpg , by(foreign ) fast
```

There are only provisions for error codes `111` and `135`, so the `table` command continues to run until it hits a wall when it cannot find the aforementioned variables.

Stata 14 and later versions check the variable(s) provided by the user in the `contents()` option and only accept numeric types, issuing a more informative error message if this is not the case.

It is also worth pointing out that `collapse` treats strings differently in more recent Stata versions.